# IIS WebSocket module is not enabled

Tags: c#, javascript, iis, websocket

I am trying to set up a web application that utilizes WebSockets.
I am running VS12_RC on Windows 7 and whenever I try to run my websocket I get a "The IIS WebSocket module is not enabled." error. Where can I turn this on at? I see IIS 8 Express in my Add or Remove Programs, but can't seem to find it in my system. I assume it was installed with VS12_RC?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WebSocket support is only available on Windows 8 and Windows Server 2012. There's a comment to this effect in the readme: http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/1286/iis-80-express-readme/

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I figured this was going to be the case.  I am so excited to start using websockets but it's been a head ache trying to get them to work

Answer (score 0):

That Site says

IIS 8.0 Express supports writing WebSocket applications

check Changes to IIS 8.0 Express - > New Features - > X64 Support - > WebSocket Support

Please let me know I am not getting it correctly.